# Count rows where one column has two values in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a column in a table which entries look like this:

```
"a=2&a=4&time=2016"
"a=2"
"p=14&a=4"
```

I want to extract occurrences of "a=X", group by X and count rows for distinct values.

So the result for above example would be:

```
a=X | count
----------
a=2 | 2
a=4 | 2
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I have no idea if this is possible and tried only:
select regexp_extract(querystring, 'a=([^&])*',0), count(*) as num
from pageview
group by regexp_extract(querystring, 'a=([^&])*',0)
order by num desc;
But this is wrong of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      col
           ,count(*)

from        pageviews
            lateral view explode (split (querystring,'&')) e as col

where       col like 'a=÷'

group by    col
```

Comment: @rohitvk - I sent it from my cellphone. Thanks for the edit :-)